# Splitting website url to keywords, multible splits

Tags: python

I am currently creating a tool which scans the URL of a website and returns the keywords as a list. For example google.com/images then the tool should give out:
{"google", "images"}
I knew how to filter the .com part out, but I have the problem that I can't split the split parts again. So I end up with the results of the first split. How do I split these parts again?

First  `run split(".") -> {"google", "com/images"}`

Second `run split("/") -> {"google", "com", "images"}`

because then I can filter things like the .com part out. I'm writing this in Python and this is my code atm.

First the error:

> " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' "

so the problem is that this is an list object and I can't split this again.

Now the code

```
url_content = input('Enter url: ')

url_split1 = url_content.split('.')

url_split2 = url_split1.split('/')

url_split3 = url_split2.split('-')

url_split4 = url_split3.split('&')

filtered = {'com', 'net'}

print(url_split4)

for key in url_split4:

    if key not in filtered:

        print(key)
```

Comment: _So i end up with the results of the first split. How do i split these parts again?_ You could use a list comprehension, for example, or just a plain loop. I'm not sure I understand what exactly the issue is. _First the error: " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' " so the problem is that this is an list object and i can't split this again._ Please provide the entire error output, as well as [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace:

```
url_content = input('Enter url: ').replace('/','.').replace('-','.').replace('&','.')
```

and then split it once:

```
url_split1 = url_content.split('.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either use python's builtin regular expressions library as follows.

```
import re
re.split('\.|\&|\-|/', url_content)
```

or you may use the string replace method.

```
url_content.replace(".", "/").replace("&", "/").replace("-", "/").split("/")
```